# Proper place to override ApplicationController methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec3

I need to override a controller method when running a test suite against my application.

I am having to put my override in my app code, which I was hoping to prevent.

```
class ApplicationController
end

if ENV['LAYOUT'] == 'test'
  class ApplicationController
    layout: "test_layout"
  end
end
```

ApplicationController does not exist for me to override in any of the spec helpers. The load order is:

1. spec_helper
2. config/application
3. rails_helper
4. application_controller

So I am setting the ENV variable in my spec_helper and redefine ApplicationController if that ENV is set. This seems messy and I would rather override ApplicationController from the /spec directory.

Is there a better place for me to override ApplicationController in the `/specs` directory?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Maybe there's a better way to achieve what you want but I don't really get why would you change the layout when testing (you already have mocks and stubs to override methods).

Comment: The main layout adds additional scripts that slows testing down. I can increase our test run by 50% if I can use a test layout.

Comment: Hmmm, personally, what I do is just wrap those scripts with an `unless Rails.env.test? do ..... end` block, so they are not rendered on the view when the environment is `test`. You won't have to mantain two layouts this way.

Comment: I have other methods in AppController that need to be overridden.